# Get value from a object

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

my collection contains documents like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("585a7886e4b06aec5d1d1639"),
    "name": "somename",
    "owner": "someowner",
    "slots": 50,
    "gold": 0,
    "tag": "sometext",
    "motd": "sometext",
    "purchases": [],
    "members": {
        "membername1": {
            "rank": 2
        },
        "membername2": {
            "rank": 5
        },
        "membername3": {
            "rank": 3
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get int value from "members.membername.rank".
how do I get this value, knowing only membername?

Comment: imho your datastructure is wrong. members should be a list like `"members": [{ "membername":"name", "rank":3 }, { "membername":"name2", "rank":5 }]`. this would be correct and would make it much easier

Comment: ok, now i have structure like <code>"members" : [
                {
                        "membername" : "name",
                        "rank" : 3
                },
                {
                        "membername" : "name2",
                        "rank" : 5
                }
        ]</code> How i can get this value now?

Comment: you definitely should do reasearch and read the getting started. you now can work with `find` and `eq` - look here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/

Comment: You can try something like this. Match on member name and use positional operator to project the matching array element.  `db.<insertcollectionname>.find({"members.membername": "name"}, {_id: 0, "members.$":1})`. Output will look like this `{ "members" : [ { "membername" : "name", "rank" : 3 } ] }`

Answer (score 0):

The following code excludes the document's ID and gets only the `rank` for `memername1`

```
List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.asList(new Document("$project", new Document("rank", "$members.membername1.rank").append("_id", false)));
return ApiResponse.withBody(coll.aggregate(pipeline).first().getInteger("rank"));
```